# Execute .cmd with parameters from powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, cmd

I am a complete novice when it comes to powershell and something that seems like it would be so simple is completely escaping me...

I can't run an old .cmd file which I need to call with a parameter. When using cmd.exe I would navigate to the directory where the .cmd is held,

```
cd C:\MyDirectory\BlahBlah1
```

Then type the name of my script followed by the parameter I want to pass

```
MyScript.cmd Parameter1
```

The cmd script would then run with the specified parameter no issues. How would I launch the .cmd script with the specified parameter from powershell?

I have been trying,
    cd C:\MyDirectory\BlahBlah1
Which takes me to my directory with no issues.. Then,

```
Invoke-Item MyScript.cmd Parameter1
```

With result

Invoke-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Parameter1'.
At line:1 char:12
+ Invoke-Item <<<<  MyScript.cmd bup
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeItemCommand

Comment: What did you do and what results you get?

Comment: @PetSerAl please see above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute `.cmd` files same way as you do it in `cmd`, but you have to explicitly specify to look for `.cmd` in current directory:

```powershell
.\MyScript.cmd Parameter1
```

Comment: This is the right answer. [**Accepting Answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
$args1 = "argument1"
$args2 = "argument2"

& "C:\Temp\testcmd.cmd" $args1 $args2
```